# How to access values separately from object

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have this object returned in this way:

```
Object: {
    "data":"data1",
    "value":"value1, value2"
}
```

If i just call using `Object.value` it will return both values. Right now I want to access value1 and value2 separately and assign them to a separate variable. E.g `var first = value1, var second = value2`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The value of the property is the single string `"value1, value2"`. If you want those separately, you have to split the string into multiple parts (such as an array). See the linked question's answers for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. Forgot about the split function